# What's the definition of socket,why need it and how it works?

Tags: sockets

I know that socket is widely used in network program, and I can write code with it. But I can't understand some things:

## 1. Why do we need sockets?

If it is used to distinguish application layer program by network layer, why not use the appliation name or other uniqueue attribute?

Is socket a standard?

Is socket just a structure in linux or other os?

## 2. How socket works?

There is a lot of functions around socket,such as bind, accept, listen, send.For example, send() send msg to dest by TCP, and how it send msg to network-layer? Does it send msg to tcp buffer? How network layer process read the tcp buffer data and how to send data to the lower layer process?

If I used `send(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len, int flags)` function, the first arg 'sockfd' is a undefined socket, such as a random int,  what result will cause and why? What does the os process?

Comment: This is too broad a question for SO. I suggest you read the book "Unix Network Programming", it explains it very well.

Comment: Why are you trying to jam all your questions about sockets into this one question? Also, the questions do not display a good faith attempt on your part to answer your own questions first.

Answer (score 3):

Sockets have their origin in Berkeley (hence the name [Berkeley sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets)) and they are meant to be a "standard" abstraction for interprocess communication via network.

1. POSIX sockets are a standard, and they are, basically, the original Berkeley sockets (as for the interface)
2. the interface is very well documented, and it specifies what happens if, for example, you use a random int for the `sockfd` parameter in `send`. "and how it send msg to network-layer?" is a matter of how the library is implemented, and has a different answer on different OSs. From the user point of view, this should be of no concern.

Answer (score 3):

On UNIX, a socket is a kind of file descriptor. On Windows, a SOCKET is a kind of HANDLE. File descriptors and HANDLEs are the way these OSs allow various operations (such as read and write) to be performed on resources. A network connection is thus considered an OS resource provided by the network service of the OS.

The socket API is more or less standard, although each OS may provide OS specific APIs as well as OS specific options for the standard APIs.

The underlying implementation of a socket very likely involves a structure.

How the OS implements the socket APIs is not much different than it would implement other system calls. The `send()` API is eventually converted into a system call that delivers data to the network stack. The network stack will manage its own buffers, but a `send()` will typically cause the data in userspace to be copied to the network buffer (which is not unlike what happens when the `write()` system call is called). The network stack processes the data through its code, passing it to the different layers (typically: socket -> TCP -> IP -> ethernet driver). At the lowest layer, it is similar to any device driver the OS uses to communicate with a physical device.

When you pass a non-socket file descriptor to `send()`, I would expect you get an error, either `EBADF`, `EINVAL`, or `ENOTSOCK`, most likely.